# __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'cachedir' when importing top2vec

Tags: python, machine-learning, topic-modeling

I keep getting this error when importing top2vec.

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In [1], line 1
----> 1 from top2vec import Top2Vec

File ~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\top2vec\__init__.py:1
----> 1 from top2vec.Top2Vec import Top2Vec
      3 __version__ = '1.0.27'

File ~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\top2vec\Top2Vec.py:12
     10 from gensim.models.phrases import Phrases
     11 import umap
---> 12 import hdbscan
     13 from wordcloud import WordCloud
     14 import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

File ~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\hdbscan\__init__.py:1
----> 1 from .hdbscan_ import HDBSCAN, hdbscan
      2 from .robust_single_linkage_ import RobustSingleLinkage, robust_single_linkage
      3 from .validity import validity_index

File ~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\hdbscan\hdbscan_.py:509
    494         row_indices = np.where(np.isfinite(matrix).sum(axis=1) == matrix.shape[1])[0]
    495     return row_indices
    498 def hdbscan(
    499     X,
    500     min_cluster_size=5,
    501     min_samples=None,
    502     alpha=1.0,
    503     cluster_selection_epsilon=0.0,
    504     max_cluster_size=0,
    505     metric="minkowski",
    506     p=2,
    507     leaf_size=40,
    508     algorithm="best",
--> 509     memory=Memory(cachedir=None, verbose=0),
    510     approx_min_span_tree=True,
    511     gen_min_span_tree=False,
    512     core_dist_n_jobs=4,
    513     cluster_selection_method="eom",
    514     allow_single_cluster=False,
    515     match_reference_implementation=False,
    516     **kwargs
    517 ):
    518     """Perform HDBSCAN clustering from a vector array or distance matrix.
    519 
    520    Parameters
   (...)
    672        Density-based Cluster Selection. arxiv preprint 1911.02282.
    673    """
    674     if min_samples is None:

TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'cachedir'
```

Python version: 3.9.7 (64-bit)

Have installed MSBuild

No errors when pip installing this package

Does anyone know a solution to this problem or experienced a similar problem?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

- **UPDATE 12 November 2022:**

There is [new release (ver. 0.8.29) of hdbscan](https://pypi.org/project/hdbscan/) from 31 Oct. 2022 that fix the issue. See my original answer for more details.

**Original Answer:**

It looks like you are using latest (as of 23 Sept 2022) versions of `hdbscan` and `joblib` packages available on PyPI.

`cachedir` was removed from `joblib.Memory` [in commit on 2 Feb 2022 as depreciated](https://github.com/joblib/joblib/blame/3fb7fbde772e10415f879e0cb7e5d986fede8460/joblib/memory.py#L910). The latest version on PyPi is [ver. 1.2.0 released on Sep 16, 2022](https://pypi.org/project/joblib/1.2.0/), i.e. it incorporate this change

The relevant part of `hdbscan` source code on GitHub was [updated on 16 Sept 2022](https://github.com/scikit-learn-contrib/hdbscan/blame/ccd8535d3db241398afa9299cd279c4cd85133f5/hdbscan/hdbscan_.py#L509). Unfortunately the latest (as of 23 Sept 2022) `hdbscan` release on PyPi is [ver. 0.8.28 released on Feb 8, 2022](https://pypi.org/project/hdbscan/0.8.28/) and still not updated. It still use `memory=Memory(cachedir=None, verbose=0)`

One possible solution is to force using `joblib` version before `cachedir` was removed - ver. 1.1.0 as of Oct 7, 2021. However note my edits below.

- UPDATE 29 Sept 2022:

There are open issues on `hdbscan` repo ([#563](https://github.com/scikit-learn-contrib/hdbscan/issues/563)) and ([#565](https://github.com/scikit-learn-contrib/hdbscan/issues/565)).

**Note [there is vulnerability CVE-2022-21797](https://nvd.nist.gov/vuln/detail/CVE-2022-21797) when using joblib < 1.2.0**

- UPDATE 12 November 2022:

There is [new release (ver. 0.8.29) of hdbscan](https://pypi.org/project/hdbscan/) from 31 Oct. 2022.

Comment: tried to install top2vec directly from github didn't work. But as you suggested downgrading joblib worked!!

Comment: It didn't work because top2vec and hdbscan requirements always use latest versions of dependencies on PyPI.

Comment: Thanks! This worked for me by adding ```joblib = "==1.1.0"``` to my pyproject.toml file

Comment: @AlfieGrace, note my edit about vulnerability CVE-2022-21797 when using joblib==1.1.0

Answer (score 11):

Thank you! It worked for me. I downgraded the `joblib` package by using `pip install --upgrade joblib==1.1.0`; however, please be advised that this version of `joblib` has a known vulnerability of [Arbitrary Code Execution via the `pre_dispatch` flag in `Parallel()` class due to the `eval()` statement](https://security.snyk.io/package/pip/joblib/1.1.0). So, please use it with caution and not in production. Happy coding. :)

Comment: I got the same issue when I tried to import BERTopic from bertopic. When I upgraded joblib, it worked. Thanks.